# Connection between my Android APP and one Bluetooth adapter plugged in my PC

Tags: android, bluetooth, dongle

I'm trying to do that connection but I'm always receive this error: "Connection Refused".
The devices are paring but after that I received this exception.

I'm trying to connect with using the correct address and I'm trying to create the socket connection this way:

> Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class} );
>   tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

I tried using one UUID, but I always received "Service discovery failed"

If you need I put more code or I explain better you can say. I'll appreciate any help, I already tried everything that I found in the internet but nothing worked =(

Comment: You might want to specify which version of android you're working with. Gingerbread was notorious for Bluetooth issues depending on the device.

Comment: My android version is 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it seems like there is no server on the device you are trying to connect to or the server was not running / listening.
What application is running on the PC ? Did you setup the Bluetooth Serial ports on the PC and have some application open it and wait for some data to come in.

Comment: I don't think the problem is this, because my app is paring the devices, the problem is after paring. I can't wait to some data if there isn't one connection.

Comment: Pairing is different from connection, Pairing can happen even without any service running, but to connect to a service the service should be running

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot. I create a Server and now is working!